# scroll a chart and a ListView together

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I would like to build a screen with a single scroll of a graph and a ListView together

Currently with this code I rightly only get the ListView scroll (see fig)

```
  Widget loadStat() {
    pagesStatPageWidget = _buildPagesStat();
    pagesStatGraphWidget = _graphWidget();
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        pagesStatGraphWidget,
        pagesStatPageWidget,
      ],
    );
  }

Widget _graphWidget() {
    return Container(
      width: 200.0,
      height: 200.0,
      child: new GaugeChart(
        _createSampleData(),
        animate: true,
      ),
    );
}

Widget _buildPagesStat() {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0), 
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return _buildLogStat(pagesList[i], titolo);
        },
        itemCount: pagesList.length,
      ),
    );
}
```

[image]

I read that the solution should be inserting chart and ListView under a column
but I made several attempts with Column, Flexible, List without any success.

Can someone help me?

Special thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a `CustomScrollView`

try this out:

```dart
  return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: your_graph_widget), //Your graph widget
          SliverList(), //Reformat your list into a sliver list.
]
)
```

Comment: great! it seems working for me
but I'm still working to reformat list into sliver list
many thanks user76706055

Comment: Great! I believe this is what it should look like (I'm on my phone so there might be some syntax errors)

SliverList(
delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
 _buildLogStat(pagesList[i], titolo);
}
childCount: pagesList.length
))

Comment: your suggestion run perfectly!
many thanks for all
have a nice day!